Modification to sudoers not working correctly
I added the last line so I could run a systemctl suspend command
in a cron job.
But then when I used synaptic-pkexec, it would open but it would not let me apply to install programs. Also gparted would not open.
What is wrong?
# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d

#andy Scientist =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl poweroff,/usr/bin/systemctl halt,/usr/bin/systemctl reboot,/usr/bin/systemctl suspend

